# How to get data from SQLite database using GreenDao

Tags: android, android-sqlite, greendao

I am using greendao for the first time. and it is going good. I have generated code and entities. I have put the basic data and checked it using sqlite browser and all data is there in specific fields.

Now there are some method in the dao class and I have used the insert method to insert the data. But Now I have to get data so looking how to return the data. 
here are my some of the questions:

1. How to get data ?
2. Is there any built in method in there ? or I need to make my own and where?
3. I need to know when should I need to close connection and what things I need to take in account while using greendao ?

please provide some source code or any demo code on How I can get data. I have no source code to share on , As rest is basic code generated by the dao. And I think it would be childish question , but I have not found any documentation telling about its method it have etc.  Please help me in my problem described above and also clear my confusions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To retrieve your data you have to use greenDao `Queries`. You can specify your own conditions to match rows.

**Example (extracted from docs)**:

```
List joes = userDao.queryBuilder()
    .where(Properties.FirstName.eq("Joe"))
    .orderAsc(Properties.LastName)
    .list();
```

Here is the docs (with demos): http://greenrobot.org/greendao/documentation/queries/

Comment: where should I write these lines ?

Comment: @AllayKhalil You can write this in your `Activity`.
You have to get a instance of your `Dao` class, and use `queryBuilder` method to filter data, as in above **example**. I suggest you to read this great tutorial: http://www.devteam83.com/en/tutorial-greendao-from-scratch-part-1/

Comment: great One thing more, While reading your link in the answer I saw two things one is .list() and other is listLazy () , I got little by their explanation and that is , it loads the items in the list like lazy list ? but I am confused as  lazy list is graphical thing ?

Comment: The `list()` method run the query, build the list with entities and load it into memory. When using `listLazy()`, the entities are loaded into memory only when are accessed. Therefore, you if do not access the entity, it is not loaded into memory.